# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, can't find a similar scenario in other questions

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am making a program to send people happy birthday emails on their birthday. i keep getting the error in the title. From every question i have read on here it appears i can't get hold of an integer in my dictionary, but that doesn't make any sense.

```
LETTERS = ["letter_1.txt", "letter_2.txt", "letter_3.txt"]

bd = p.read_csv("birthdays.csv")
data = bd.to_dict(orient="index")

now = d.datetime.now()
day = now.day
month = now.month

for d in data:
    bday = d['day']
    bmonth = d['month']
    if day == bday and month == bmonth:
        recipient = d['email']
        letter_choice = r.choice(LETTERS)
        with open(f"./letter_templates/{letter_choice}", mode="r") as l:
            orig_letter = l.read()
            r_letter = orig_letter.replace(PLACEHOLDER, d['name'])
            with s.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
                connection.starttls()
                connection.login(user=MY_EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
                connection.sendmail(
                    from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
                    to_addrs=recipient,
                    msg=f"subject:Happy Birthday\n\n{r_letter}"
                )
```

how can i get my if statement to check the day and month from my dictionary?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoods\zip_downloads_for_class\birthday-wisher-hard-start\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    bday = d['day']
           ~^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please post the exact full error message you are getting.  It will help others understand your problem.

Comment: Yes, what @Arusekk said. Also, I think Gmail no longer allows users to send email from code.

Comment: Change `for d in data:` to `for index, d in data.items():`.  When you iterate over a dictionary you just get the keys.  Here the keys are the index values which are just integers.  Also note that when you name your loop variable `d` you lose the reference to the module you aliased as `d`.

Comment: i added the full error message, and yes, it does you just have to use an app password. Last night i sent several emails successfully.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that did the trick, thank you so much, i should have known that!

Comment: You really should just not use pandas here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga care to elaborate? i was following a lesson in a course i am taking and that's what i was supposed to do. i'd like to hear your thoughts further.

Comment: @MathewStill you are just using pandas to parse the csv, which you then turn into a list of dictionaries. You never actually use any of the pandas operations on the dataframe. Instead, you should just use the standard libary `csv` module. Just note, it treats everything as strings, so you'll have to convert each item to the appropriate type (I guess that is one thing pandas is doing for you)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `data` is a dictionary with integer keys.  You most likely want to iterate through its values instead of keys.

```py
LETTERS = ["letter_1.txt", "letter_2.txt", "letter_3.txt"]

bd = p.read_csv("birthdays.csv")
data = bd.to_dict(orient="index")

now = d.datetime.now()
day = now.day
month = now.month

for d in data.values():  # <---
    bday = d['day']
    bmonth = d['month']
    if day == bday and month == bmonth:
        recipient = d['email']
        letter_choice = r.choice(LETTERS)
        with open(f"./letter_templates/{letter_choice}", mode="r") as l:
            orig_letter = l.read()
            r_letter = orig_letter.replace(PLACEHOLDER, d['name'])
            with s.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
                connection.starttls()
                connection.login(user=MY_EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
                connection.sendmail(
                    from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
                    to_addrs=recipient,
                    msg=f"subject:Happy Birthday\n\n{r_letter}"
                )
```